# Funções que são apelidos (alias) devem ser usadas ou não?

Tags: php, funções, alias

Lembro-me que, há um tempo atrás, quando eu estava iniciando na programação com PHP, vi em alguns tutoriais uma recomendação, advertindo que era pra evitar o uso de algumas funções que são apelidos para outras.

Não sei se estou enganado, mas no próprio Manual do PHP, quando você entrava na página de uma função que era um alias (como por exemplo `session_commit` e `sizeof`), tinha um aviso mais ou menos assim:

> A função `y` é um apelido para a função `x`, portanto o seu uso deve ser evitado, pois pode ser removido em versões futuras.

Posso estar enganado, mas tenho a impressão que houve uma época onde comentavasse que *as novas versões do php removeriam todos os alias de funções, para deixar a coisa mais organizada*.

Mas o que tenho notado é que, mesmo após o PHP 7 ser lançado, os alias de funções continuam lá, e não há nenhuma recomendação quando a usar ou não os mesmos.

Exemplos:

- [session_commit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-commit.php)
- [sizeof](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sizeof.php)

Gostaria de saber se realmente há algum perigo em usar essas funções sinônimas/apelidos, por conta de ter risco de ser removido no futuro.

Usar apelidos de funções poderia ser ruim também do ponto de vista de algum padrão de codificação em PHP, como por exemplo o PSR?

Por exemplo, teria algum problema em usar `sizeof` ao invés de usar `count`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal é sempre usar o 'idioma' raiz ou seja o nome orginal da função. A equipe que cuida do desenvolvimento faz quase de tudo para manter a compatibilidade versões mais novas com as anteriores então algo desorganizado demorar para se elminado. Lembre que esses alias foram definido em algum contexto.

Funções que são utilizadas bastante dificilmente teriam algum alias removido como por exemplo `join()`/`implode()` pois isso causaria uma enorma incompatibilidade em códigos.

Agora um exemplo de várias alias eliminados está na biblioteca do MySQLi, veja [mysqli_bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-bind-param.php) / [mysqli_stmt_bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: Bacana, cara. Consegui um exemplo no manual de depreciação por ser sinônimo. Eu cacei isso pra todo lado e não achei, kkkk +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters faltou faro para achar :D